# Can employers see my edit history on Linked In?

Tags: linkedin, privacy

**What "secret" information might LinkedIn be sharing with employers?** Is there anywhere where I can find a description of such? LinkedIn doesn't appear to be disclosing that information openly *(unsurprisingly)*.

For example: I worked in my youth as a lifeguard for 3 summers. However, when I built my LinkedIn profile it had been a long time, I mis-remembered, and filled instead only 2 summers. When I later found out about that mistake I didn't update it because I feared LinkedIn might track that I was "extending"/"making up" work periods and share that information with employers, deeming me as a "liar".

Another example: I've been years not looking for a job. After I applied to a few job offers found on LinkedIn I suddenly started receiving messages from people with job offers, indicating that they were being informed by LinkedIn that I was actively looking for a new job.

Another example: when I started my current job my title was "Performance Tester". Sometime after, for "marketing" purposes, my title was changed to "Performance Test Analyst" because it sounded better. Now, again for the reason that it sounds better, my title is "Performance Engineer". Accordingly, I've been changing my title on LinkedIn. Now I'm thinking that employers might be able to see a history of those changes and judge me as a liar that goes around inflating its job titles.

*(when people get into "fault finding more", like people recruiting often get in to, any possible "excuse" serves to place fault on a candidate and exclude him from their lists - I'm concerned with how many excuses I'm opening myself to)*

So Can employers see my edit history on Linked In?

---

**Bonus question: if employers are able to see more "secret" info from LinkedIn than I want, what can I do about it?** If I "delete" my account will employers still be able to access my history (find me by name and still see my history)? Can I demand that LinkedIn actually deletes my data (I'm a EU citizen but LinkedIn is .. not sure)? I remember the Ashley Madison case where people could only delete their accounts by paying and they still weren't getting their data deleted.

Comment: I think LinkedIn has far more interesting things to do than to track you that closely :)

Comment: **Tin foil hat paranoia is not what this site is about.** I'm voting to close this question because the Workplace is not WikiLeaks or a conspiracy forum.

Comment: It's easy. Register yourself as an employer and look up your profile. But in that case linkedin will know that you did so, and know you're on to them, so they might not show you anything.

Comment: Jokes aside, this can be salvaged to a good question. Going along the lines of _can employers see edits in my linkedin entries_ and _could that negatively affect their perception of me_ would be more acceptable for this site, and would do away with the accusations of tinfoil-hattery.

Comment: @Lilienthal Usually when people are paranoid about something it means one of two things: 1) they lied about something and is worried, or 2) they feel something embarrassing happened and they are worried about others finding out. If it is #1, the simple solution is to not lie. And if it is #2, perhaps it is not as embarrassing as you may think.

Comment: @rath There might be some value in knowing what employers have access to with LinkedIn's advanced features, but I would think that's covered sufficiently by the website. As for anything beyond that, even *if* it was possible, no *sane* hiring manager is going to bother and you don't want to work for the insane ones anyway.

Comment: @Lilienthal - linkedin is simply a lot different from Facebook as far as API usages and what you can get out of it.  It has simply not published the microdata and change reports via their API that you "used to" be able to mine out of Facebook (I am sure you still can but I haven't done FB dev in years).  So the paranoia might be valid given that other sites do it but there simply isn't the vehicles to do this in LinkedIn.  You can look at their dev API page and see it is just REST hooks to manage profiles (company pages too).

Comment: `When I later found out about that mistake I didn't update it because I feared LinkedIn might track that I was "extending"/"making up" work periods` - If you truly are worried about this, then you probably shouldn't be publishing *anything* online. Conceivably someone could be tracking your published page edits by saving local copies, or they could be using the Waybackmachine or something similar to see your past versions. - This works the other way, by the way. Try looking at a potential employer's past web site(s) if you're curious.

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing secret that employers can see on LinkedIn.  This is simply ludicrous because there would be SO MANY employers that "secret" information would be available to millions and therefore wouldn't be secret.  Also if you apply via jobs on LinkedIn this is available knowledge via their API and anyone with a premium account or others with API use can see this (you are applying - so it isn't a secret).

Also everyone changes their info on LinkedIn all the time.  To make updates or to correct things.  The only thing an employer would care about is if you lied on the information you gave them or your latest info.

Note: That I did have a web tool that used their API.  Their API is very closed and more about using their SSO or just posting things easier.  There is very little that I could see the API being used for in terms of data mining that you couldn't get from their premium searches (or just regular indexed searches if you know where to look).

Comment: `The only thing an employer would care about is if you lied on the information you gave them or your latest info.` Exactly.  This is why they do reference checks.

Answer (score 0):

If you only provided information x, y, and z, then that is pretty much all they can possibly share with employers, if they in fact do that. So if you only gave your name, email, and employment history, then that is pretty much all they can find. It's not like linked in can "discover" something about you and it's very doubtful they would call everyone on your list and ask about you when they have millions of other users.

Of course, if you put false information on there, and they - the employers - happen to find out, then that would only hinder your job searching. It would also cause you to potentially lose connections on linkedin and possibly spread reputation about you such as person A knowing person B at another company and finding out you lied to person A and now person B wants nothing to do with you.